# Azure VM not communicating over IPSec VPN

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines, azure-networking

I have setup an IPSec VPN between Azure gateway and a remote Cisco Firewall. I can't RDP into local Windows servers in the azure vnet from remote site machine. However I can connect to the remote site VPN using Azure network based local machine.

I suspected this could be due to a firewall rule on the remote firewall, but it was allowed and not receiving any traffic from the Azure site.

any hint about what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Routing.  A key portion that people normally miss is to tell the Local system to route traffic for Azure IP address space to Azure.

In most system it's called a Static Route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It also gets tricky when you have app services that are not on a machine. You have to do routing table additions on the Azure side to get the app service talking to anything in house.